# magento compile time error

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.1, compile

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02>php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 4 secs 96.0 MiB
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02\vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\Wishlist.php on line 1
```

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out-of-memory errors.

I have tried in all directions...

Comment: welcome to stackexchange, try running:

php -dmemory_limit=7G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: plz try `php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile` Or you need to increase memory in php.ini

Comment: @Devidas

It works for me,,,,but after reaching 88% i got error like this:-

Plugin list generation... 8/9 [========================>---]  88% 3 mins 382.0 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:

  Warning: Use of undefined constant ‘ - assumed '‘' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02\ve
  ndor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 159

Comment: @Pawan

I used php -d memory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile....

,but after reaching 88% i got error like this:- Plugin list generation... 8/9 [========================>---] 88% 3 mins 382.0 MiB In ErrorHandler.php line 61: Warning: Use of undefined constant ‘ - assumed '‘' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02\ve ndor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 159

Comment: @John

It works for me,,,,but after reaching 88% i got error like this:- Plugin list generation... 8/9 [========================>---] 88% 3 mins 382.0 MiB In ErrorHandler.php line 61: Warning: Use of undefined constant ‘ - assumed '‘' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-ce-2.4.1-2020-09-25-04-08-02\ve ndor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php on line 159 –

Comment: @RakshithRai, whatever plugin you've been working on, you've got an undefined constant, as in you've written something you've meant to be a variable but something's gone wrong and php/Magento isn't reading it as a variable

Comment: @John,

do i need to reinstall magento and php

Comment: @RakshithRai if the Magento installation you have is completely unedited, no extra modules put in and such, then yeah probably a Magento reinstall would be needed. If you have custom code you've written or you have got from other code developers, chances are its something faulty within that. Your PHP installation is going to be absolutely fine though

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like your cli has only 128MB of memory allocated. Increase this value to at 256MB or 512MB at least.
You can either increase increase memory limit in php.ini or directly run this command

```
php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: i really appreciate your support.
but after reaching 88%..i got error..i used two code in "PluginListGenerator.php".i.e,
first i used to this code..then i got error in 88%:
existing code :- $cacheId = implode('|', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "|" . $this->cacheId;
after i replaced existing code to modified code.i got same error in 88%:
modified code :- $cacheId = implode(‘-’, $this->scopePriorityScheme) . “-” . $this->cacheId;
after using this two code..i got error after reaching 88%.